# Prolog constraints in a list

Tags: prolog

I have a problem in prolog which requires all possible permutations of a list of four elements(an element can be 1,2 or X) but I have to add 2 contraints to that list.The last element of it can not be the symbol "X" and the  permutation can't contain the symbol "1" more than 2 times.I'm not sure where and how should I put those constraints.Can anyone give me ideeas?

```
domains
    elem=symbol
    list=elem*

predicates
    elimin(elem,list,list)
    perm(list,list)


clauses
    elimin(H,T,[H|T]).
    elimin(H,[A|T],[A|X]):-
            elimin(H,T,X).
    perm([],[]).
    perm([H|T],X):-
        perm(T,T1),
        elimin(H,T1,X).
```

Current code:

```
    domains
        elem=symbol
        list=elem*

    predicates
        valid(list)
        generate(list)
        count(list,elem,integer)
        member(symbol,list)
    clauses
        valid(S):- 
            generate(S),count(S,1,C),C<2.

        generate([A,B,C,D]) :-
            member(A,["1","2","X"]),
            member(B,["1","2","X"]),
            member(C,["1","2","X"]),
            member(D,["1","2"]).
    member(X,[X|_]).
    member(X,[_|T]):- member(X,T).      
    count([],_,0).
        count([H|T],X,C):- H<>X,
                count(T,X,C).
        count([H|T],X,C1):- H=X,
                count(T,X,C),
                C1=C+1.
```

Comment: if you remove one 1 you're left with 3 elements to permute?

Comment: Write the test for those conditions and you will find that you have written the code.

Comment: The second condition makes no sense. If the permutations can't contain a "1" more than twice, the original list can't either.

Comment: @SQB I updated the requirement.The only values I'm supposed to find in that list are 1,2 and X.So there may be solutions like [2,2,2,2] or [1,1,1,1].

Comment: then you're not looking for permutations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment it's apparent your perm/2 is useless.

The obvious way is to join the generator with a filter accepting only valid sequences.
If the generator avoid to put a 1 in last position, it's sufficient a procedure count/3.
The generator it's easy to write with a non deterministic member/2.

Note: it's handy to keep constants lowercase (`x` instead of `X`).

```
valid(S) :- generate(S), count(S,1,C), C < 2.

generate([A,B,C,D]) :-
    member(A,[1,2,x]),
    member(B,[1,2,x]),
    member(C,[1,2,x]),
    member(D,[2,x]).
```

see if you can write count/3 by yourself...

Comment: `count([],X,0).
count([H|T],X,C):-
H=X,
C=C+1,
count(T,X,C)`
is this ok?

Comment: You miss the 'else' branch, when `H\=X`. Then count will fail...And can't reassign to `C`. Use `C1 is C+1`

Comment: `count([],X,0). 
count([H|T],X,C):- H=X, C is C+1, count(T,X,C). 
count([H|T],X,C):- H\=X,count(T,X,C).`
Ok,I suppose it should work now,right?

Comment: should be `count([H|T],X,C1):- H=X, count(T,X,C), C1 is C+1.`

Comment: tryed that,it says gives the "undeclared predicate or misspelling",positioning the cursor under C1 in `C1 is C+1`
I updated the post with the current code.

Comment: you need then `... count([H|T],X,C1):- H=X, ..., C1=C+1` because your Prolog doesn't know is/2. And you miss the other 2 rules

Comment: Fixed that. Now it says there are no clauses for the predicate member which I suppose it means that he doesn't know what member does.Something like this will do the trick? `member(X,[H|T]):-H,!,member(X,T).`

Comment: `member(X,[X|_]). member(X,[_|T]) :- member(X,T).` but you count/3 as seen in your code is not yet ok. Try to correct it before, running some test, or the debugger

Comment: There seems to be a problem with `member` when I try to run it indepentently I get an warning that `X` is not boundeded in the clause and if I step over it,it generates an infinite list.